# How to get the second element of index in 2d list

Tags: python, function, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get the second index of element in 2nd list in python. The problem is that I can't do that because I get a problem free variable x referenced before assignment in enclosing space. My idea is for example if I got A in plaintext x will be 0, if i got b in key y will be 1. So I want to get the first index for letter in key, the second for letter in plaintext. It is possible? My code:

```
def making_dimensional_list(grid):
    global grid2
    grid2 = [list(line) for line in grid.split("\n")]
    return grid2
print(making_dimensional_list("""ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA
CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAB
DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC
EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCD
FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDE
GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEF
HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFG
IJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGH
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHI
KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJ
LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJK
MNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKL
NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM
OPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMN
PQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
QRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
RSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ
STUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
TUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS
UVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
VWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU
WXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV
XYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW
YZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX
ZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY"""))



def making_2_lists(keyword,text):
    global key,plaintext
    key= []
    # plaintext = "to jest bardzo tajny tekst"
    text = text.upper()
    text = text.replace(" ", "")
    plaintext = list(text)
    # keyword = "tajne"
    keyword = keyword.upper()
    keyword = keyword.replace(" ", "")
    keyword = list(keyword)
    for j in range(len(text)):
        key.append(keyword[j%len(keyword)])
    return plaintext,key
print(making_2_lists("tajne","To jest bardzo tajny tekst"))

def encrypt_vigenere(plaintext,key,grid2):
    for symbol in plaintext:
        x = [x for symbol in grid2 if symbol in grid2[0][x]]
    for letter in key:
        y = [y for letter in grid2 if letter in grid2[y][0]]


    return x,y
print(encrypt_vigenere(plaintext,grid2,key))
```

Comment: I see that my question is badly reveived by community. What is wrong with that question? My english is not the best, but I think everything should be understable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you're getting an error because the code `if symbol in grid2[0][x]` is using `x` as an index before it is defined.

And the long answer is that there's a lot going wrong in your code. To avoid this answer being to broad, I'm only going to talk about this bit:

```
def encrypt_vignere(plaintext,key,grid2):
  for symbol in plaintext:
    x = [x for symbol in grid2 if symbol in grid2[0][x]]
  return x
```

Before we go any further, I'm going to re-name the list `x` as `result` to avoid confusion with the list index `x`, like so:

```
def encrypt_vignere(plaintext,key,grid2):
  for symbol in plaintext:
    result = [x for symbol in grid2 if symbol in grid2[0][x]]
  return result
```

Now, let's turn your list comprehension into a regular loop, so it's easier to see what's going wrong. Your code is equivalent to:

```
def encrypt_vignere(plaintext,key,grid2):
  for symbol in plaintext:
    result = []
    for symbol in grid2:
      if symbol in grid2[0][x]:
        result.append(x)
  return result
```

There are a few problems here. Let's solve them one by one:

1. You are repeatedly overwriting `result` in every iteration of the outer loop, rather than appending to it. This can be solved by moving the declaration of `result` outside the outer loop, like so:

```
def encrypt_vignere(plaintext,key,grid2):
  result = []
  for symbol in plaintext:
    for symbol in grid2:
      if symbol in grid2[0][x]:
        result.append(x)
  return result
```

2. The nested loops `for symbol in plaintext:` and `for symbol in grid2:` both use `symbol` as the loop variable name. The `symbol` from the inner loop will [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the `symbol` from the outer loop, so that `symbol` from the outer loop can't be used. Let's avoid this by re-naming the two `symbol`s to `plaintext_symbol` and `grid_symbol`, as:

```
def encrypt_vignere(plaintext,key,grid2):
  result = []
  for plaintext_symbol in plaintext:
    for grid_symbol in grid2:
      if plaintext_symbol in grid2[0][x]:
        result.append(x)
  return result
```

3. The loop `for grid_symbol in grid2` is looping over the list of lists `grid2`, so `grid_symbol` will be a list each time. But you want to compare the symbols in `plaintext` with the symbols in `grid2[0]`, so let's fix that:

```
def encrypt_vignere(plaintext,key,grid2):
  result = []
  for plaintext_symbol in plaintext:
    for grid_symbol in grid2[0]:
      if plaintext_symbol in grid2[0][x]:
        result.append(x)
  return result
```

4. The loop index `x` hasn't been defined before it is used. You want `x` to index `grid2[0]`, so let's define `x` using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def encrypt_vignere(plaintext,key,grid2):
  result = []
  for plaintext_symbol in plaintext:
    for x,grid_symbol in enumerate(grid2[0]):
      if plaintext_symbol in grid2[0][x]:
        result.append(x)
  return result
```

5. The comparison `if plaintext_symbol in grid2[0][x]` is checking if `plaintext_symbol` is `in` `grid[0][x]`, but `grid2[0][x]` is a scalar not a list. Let's replace `in` with `==`. Also, `grid2[0][x]` is exactly what we have defined `grid_symbol` to be, so let's use `grid_symbol` instead:

```
def encrypt_vignere(plaintext,key,grid2):
  result = []
  for plaintext_symbol in plaintext:
    for x,grid_symbol in enumerate(grid2[0]):
      if plaintext_symbol == grid_symbol:
        result.append(x)
  return result
```

This should now do what you want.

We can simplify this a bit by replacing the inner loop using [index](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), as

```
def encrypt_vignere(plaintext,key,grid2):
  result = []
  for plaintext_symbol in plaintext:
    result.append(grid2[0].index(plaintext_symbol))
  return result
```

and this can be wrapped back up into a list comprehension to give:

```
def encrypt_vignere(plaintext,key,grid2):
  result = [grid2[0].index(plaintext_symbol) for plaintext_symbol in plaintext]
  return result
```